# UIScrollView as subview of UICollectionViewCell - passing tap to superview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewcell, touch-event

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` subclass that contains a `UIScrollView`.

The scroll view scrolls correctly, however it intercepts taps, so that the collection view cell highlighting and selecting is not working as expected.

Setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` allows taps "through" but scrolling doesn't work (of course).

Overriding `hitTest:withEvent:` is no use as I need to know whether it's a tap or a pan before forwarding.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this today. Here's how I solved it, but there has to be a better way. I shouldn't have to put collection view selection logic into my cell code.

Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the scroll view.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewTapped:)];
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Then, in the callback, you have to simulate what would happen on a normal tap on the cell:

```
-(void) scrollViewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    UIView *tappedView = [sender view];

    while (![tappedView isKindOfClass:[UICollectionView class]]) {
        tappedView = [tappedView superview];
    }

    if (tappedView) {
        UICollectionView *collection = (UICollectionView *)tappedView;
        NSIndexPath *ourIndex = [collection indexPathForCell:self];
        BOOL isSelected = [[collection indexPathsForSelectedItems] containsObject:ourIndex];

        if (!isSelected) {
            BOOL shouldSelect = YES;
            if ([collection.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:)]) {
                shouldSelect = [collection.delegate collectionView:collection shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:ourIndex];
            }

            if (shouldSelect) {
                [collection selectItemAtIndexPath:ourIndex animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
                if ([collection.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)]) {
                    [collection.delegate collectionView:collection didSelectItemAtIndexPath:ourIndex];
                }
            }
        } else {
            BOOL shouldDeselect = YES;
            if ([collection.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(collectionView:shouldDeselectItemAtIndexPath:)]) {
                shouldDeselect = [collection.delegate collectionView:collection shouldDeselectItemAtIndexPath:ourIndex];
            }

            if (shouldDeselect) {
                [collection deselectItemAtIndexPath:ourIndex animated:NO];
                if ([collection.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(collectionView:didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:)]) {
                    [collection.delegate collectionView:collection didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:ourIndex];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```